# Height of my graph stays the same whatever I do using NVD3 in bootstrap/html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I 'm making a school project where we have to make teams of people, who will do activities and shennanigans like that (not that important).
The problem I have here, is that I'm trying to make a graph (at this stage I just imported an example from the NVD3 website, to test everything out). But when I show the graph, the height is set to a very low value, that just makes the graph almost impossible to watch.
I don't know if this is a problem with bootstrap or a problem with D3/NVD3, but I've tried changing the hight value of the graph, set it in class span 6 and stuff. But the problem persists, even If I put the line
`<div class = "span6" id="chart1"></div>`
outside of the div container. Any one know what I'm doing wrong here?

This is the code of the template for the page itself.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Team {% endblock %}

{% block toptext %}

<li><a href = "{% url 'parameter-list' %}">MyParameters</a></li>
<li><a href = "{% url 'schedules-list' %}">MySchedule</a></li>
<li class = "active"><a href = "{% url 'team-list' %}">MyTeam</a></li>
<li class = "dropdown">
    <a href= "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Mystats <b class = "caret"></b></span></a> 
    <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
        <li><a = href = "Mystats_EV.html">MyEffortValues</a></li>
        <li><a = href = "Mystats_S.html">MySleep</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href = "{% url 'user-detail' pk=user.id %}">MyAccount</a></li>
<li><a href = "{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class = "container">
 <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-lg-12">
   <h1>{{team.name}}</h1>
   <div class = "span6" id="chart1"></div>
   <div class="list-group">
    {% for staff_member in staff_members %}
    <div class = "list-group-item">
     <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-10">
                   <a href="{% url 'user-detail' pk=staff_member.id %}">{{ staff_member }}</a>
                  </div>  
                  <div class = "col-md-2">
          <p>Leider</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for member in members %}
    <div class = "list-group-item">
     <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-10">
                   <a href="{% url 'user-detail' pk=member.id %}">{{ member }}</a>
                  </div>  
                  <div class = "col-md-2">
          <p>Teamlid</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<style>
 text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
 }
 svg {
  display: block;
 }
 #chart1, svg {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
 }
</style>
<script>

var chart;

nv.addGraph(function() {
 
 chart = nv.models.lineChart()
  .options({
   transitionDuration: 300,
   useInteractiveGuideline: true
  }) ;

 // chart sub-models (ie. xAxis, yAxis, etc) when accessed directly, return themselves, not the parent chart, so need to chain separately
 chart.xAxis
  .axisLabel("Time (s)")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'))
  .staggerLabels(true)
 ;

 chart.yAxis
  .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'))
 ;

 d3.select('#chart1').append('svg')
  .datum(sinAndCos())
  .call(chart);

 nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

 return chart;
});

function sinAndCos() {
 var sin = [],
  cos = [],
  rand = [],
  rand2 = []
  ;

 for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  sin.push({x: i, y: i % 10 == 5 ? null : Math.sin(i/10) }); //the nulls are to show how defined works
  cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i/10)});
  rand.push({x:i, y: Math.random() / 10});
  rand2.push({x: i, y: Math.cos(i/10) + Math.random() / 10 })
 }

 return [
  {
   area: true,
   values: sin,
   key: "Sine Wave",
   color: "#ff7f0e"
  },
  {
   values: cos,
   key: "Cosine Wave",
   color: "#2ca02c"
  },
  {
   values: rand,
   key: "Random Points",
   color: "#2222ff"
  }
  ,
  {
   values: rand2,
   key: "Random Cosine",
   color: "#667711"
  }
 ];
}

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the base.html, because I did some imports here that might be important.

```html
<!-- i18n loads translation tags -->
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="{% static 'jquery/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- JQueryUI -->
    <script src="{% static 'jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js' %}"></script>
    <link href="{% static 'jquery/css/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap (js requires jquery) -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="{% static 'css/Styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{% static "bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
 
 <!-- NVD3 -->
 <link href="{% static 'd3/build/nv.d3.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'd3/build/nv.d3.js' %}"></script>

    {% block extraheader %}{% endblock %}

    <title>MyCoach - {% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>
    <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class = "container">
            <a href = "{% url 'index' %}" class = "navbar-brand">MyCoach</a>
            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% block toptext %}
                    <li><a href = "{% url 'parameter-list' %}">MyParameters</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "{% url 'schedules-list' %}">MySchedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "{% url 'team-list' %}">MyTeam</a></li>
                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href= "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Mystats <b class = "caret"></b></span></a> 
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a = href = "Mystats_EV.html">MyEffortValues</a></li>
                            <li><a = href = "Mystats_S.html">MySleep</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href = "{% url 'user-detail' pk=user.id %}">MyAccount</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
                    {% endblock %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     
    {% block content %} 
    {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Thnx in advance